# Multiple statements in a before update trigger vs multiple before update triggers

Tags: postgresql

I am using before update triggers to enforce some complex business rules.

One trigger has three separate checks, each running its own query.

Is this best implemented using:
a) a single before update trigger containing all three querys
b) three separate before update triggers each containing a single query

Answer (score 1):

If all checks inside triggers are connected with business rules, then one trigger gives better (more redadable) structure of checks, better control over checks order, trigger can be terminated with error in any time without processing all checks, additionaly there is always place to reuse some information obtained during check in next one.

The same functionality can be achieved with multiple triggers, but execution order of those  triggers may be not so obvious.

According to [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

> If multiple triggers of the same kind are defined for the same event,
> they will be fired in alphabetical order by name.

It' s worth mentioning, that placing complex business rules inside triggers is not recommended approach.

Comment: Where should complex business rules be placed? The triggers I am using do not update the data and just confirm the action is valid. I want to enforce integrity at the db level.

Comment: If there is backend that inserts this data, then in backend.  And if you do some checks during insert then in 99% of cases this check should also be done before,  for example, during entering data on UI. So, it's better to have a one reusable piece of logic for checking data. Business logic inside trigger is not so easy reusable in other places.  And "not recommended" is not the same as "forbidden". In many projects I used triggers but in complex projects this solution always gives troubles in long term development.